# Свойство 'zoom' отсутствует в типе 'CSSStyleDeclaration'

Tags: javascript, typescript

При обращение к `zoom`, TS выдает ошибку на отсутствие в типе `'CSSStyleDeclaration'`. Свойство отрабатывает как надо. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему, кроме как игнорирования `// @ts-ignore` ?

`document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.zoom = '2';`

`error TS2339: Property 'zoom' does not exist on type 'CSSStyleDeclaration'`

Comment: Скорее всего никак, потому что такого свойства в стандартном CSS и в самом деле не существует

Comment: Более конкретно, свойство `zoom` специально [удалили](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/commit/9d443b76aac0832d7f3c890441264d39307fe31a#diff-796971dc74a3f3cd77ca0a3a776d6fe27ab224cd501d9652dbeffcf45ba0f058L3246) (файл lib.dom.d.ts) из typescript в 2021 году. Точной причины удаления я не нашёл, но, вероятно, это связано с тем, что на Internet Explorer всем давно плевать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может это вам поможет

```js
function zoomImg(elem){
  elem.classList.toggle("zoom");
}
```

```css
img{
  width: 412px;
  height: 312px;
}

.zoom{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  zoom: 2;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp7455137.jpg" onclick="zoomImg(this)">
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариант.